# What word suits best: Who are my friends or Who my friends are?

Tags: american-english

I'm very confused with these words. Which is best applied in my project?
Please help me with this problem because I need to submit my project tomorrow.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Could you edit your question to include three or four sentences of your text? Either word-order can be used ***in specific circumstances*** and we don't know the way you're using them. Searching the site for something like **question word order** might also help you.

Comment: Here are some usages:

I don't know who my friends are.
I wonder, who my friends are.
Who are my friends?
People, who are my friends...

See what applies best to you, more context would help.

Comment: @Preetie Sekhon 'I wonder, who my friends are.' is a **misusage**.

Comment: "Suits best" for what? I doubt the following answers will have cleared up your confusion. Are you asking about the validity of these two phrases:  "Who are my friends?" and "Who my friends are?"  Do you want to know which one is a question?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on context.

*Who my friends are* is a **free relative clause**, which acts as a noun phrase inside a sentence.

> I know who my friends are.
>   Who my friends are is still unclear.

*Who are my friends* may be a freestanding **question**, or it may be a **bound relative clause** which modifies a preceding noun phrase:

> Who are my friends?
>   Carol and Brad, who are my friends, were also there.

Answer (score 1):

*Who are my friends?* Always results in a question.

*Who my friends are, ..." Mostly doesn't result in a question.

For the examples I'll be using the same meaning but said in both ways.

*Who are my friends? I don't know...*

*Who my friends are, I don't know.*

In the first example sentence the answer is definitive. He simply doesn't know who his friends are. No further information.

In the second example sentence you can use a follow up.

*Who my friends, I don't know. But I have to find out.*

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

*Who are my friends?* is a complete sentence, a question.

*Who my friends are* is not a complete sentence, but is the form that the question takes when it is embedded in another sentence, eg *I wonder who my friends are*.

Answer (score -5):

"Who are my friends?" I think is correct. Grammatically this is the subject of the sentence.

Comment: How could you possibly know it is correct when there is no context?

Comment: What do you mean that “this” (what?) is the subject of the sentence? This answer makes no sense.